# Size of my form is different and position of text is also changing is place at random

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

[screenshot of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR0ca.png)
I am using C# with Visual Studio 2010 Express, when I designed the form and placed (manually without coding,by drag and drop)  all the labels buttons etc. After Debugging some of labels are getting misplaced at slight different place and width of form is either shrinking or expanding too.
I have tried to keep auto size both true and false but same result.

Comment: Judging by the size of the text on your screen I'd guess you're having issues with DPI scaling. You can search for `c# winforms dpi aware` and try some of the results.

Comment: looks like a high dpi issue.  Can you confirm what the Window display settings for "Change the size of text, apps and other items" is in each case?  I suspect that in one situation, the scale is >100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved by Changing Auto-Scaling mode from none(or Inherit) to Dpi, so size of form will auto size according to the arrangement and not according to the text size.

Change this property:

[image: Property to change]